# is volatile HashMap enough for single writer multiple readers in java?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

only one thread will call reload() at a time.
I want to ensure that at any time, callers of get will see the content of the same latest map
instance.

Pardon me for my vague descrition on requirement.
I want to make sure that, whenever a thread call reload, all the readers will get the mapping entry from a **valid** map(both the reference and the inner structure is valid) instance, ethier the old or the new map instance is OK. But if get return a mapping from a corruptted map structure, not OK.

For initialization, assume MapCache.map is safely initialized somehow.

Is make instance variable map volatile enough to guarantee that?

```
public class MapCache {
  
  private volatile Map<String,String> map;


  public void reload() {
    this.map = newMap();
  }

  public String get(String key) {
    return map.get(key);
  }

  private Map<String,String> newMap(){
    Map<String, String> localMap = new HashMap<>();
    //init localMap;
    return localMap;
  }
}
```

In Java Concurrency in Practice, on page 52, Safe publication idioms
includes Storing a reference to it into a volatile field or AtomicReference;
which means both the reference to the object and the object’s state can be made visible to other threads at the same time.

but on page 325,

> The atomic array classes
> provide volatile access semantics to the elements of the array, a feature not available for ordinary arrays—a volatile array has volatile semantics only for the
> array reference, not for its elements.

a volatile array has volatile semantics only for the array reference, not for its elements.
I don't quite understand this sentence. It seems in contradiction to the one on page 52. So when updating an volatile array, can we be sure that other thread can see the new array and array content?

HashMap use array as it's inner states, so is volatile HashMap enough for my requirement?

> transient Node<K,V>[] table;

I searched the net and some saied volatile has hasppens-before effect(which is covered in Java Concurrency in Practice). It seems that
every time a writer thread (say ThreadA) call  reload() and update the volatile map reference, what the ThreadA sees the map inner structure will be visible to any reader thread which call get to access the volatile map reference. Is my understanding right? Some answers here says that even this is not guarrenteed.

Comment: It's not safe to have single write and multiple reads in a HashMap. If all write access happens before the first read, you wouldn't have multiple concurrent reads and writes -  so it'd be safe. Your volatile field is safe for the code you provided (but it lacks the actual write operations).

Comment: I found this post http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html. It help with better understanding volatile arrays.

Comment: The post is specific to mutable arrays. In your case, the array is effectively immutable (after it is published, it isn't updated). You just need safe publication somewhere down the road.

Comment: And for that it is sufficient to have a volatile map reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the map is effectively immutable, so doesn't get updated after it is written to the MapCache.map, then there is no problem.

What is required is that there should not be a data race. You get a data race when you have 2 conflicting actions (the reading/writing of the MapCache.map field) that are not ordered by the happens-before relation.

There is a happens-before edge between the construction (so adding the items to the buckets) of the new filled map and the writing that map to the MapCache.map field. This is due to the program order rule.

When a read of the MapCache.map field sees a particular write to that field, then there is a happens-before edge between the write and the read of that field. This is due to the volatile variable rule.

There is a happens-before edge between loading the MyCache.map field and using it (e.g. calling map.get by accessing the buckets of the Map). This is due to the program order rule.

The happens-before relation is transitive, so the is a happens-before edge between creating/filling the map and reading the content of the map and as a consequence, there is no data-race.

Your concern about the array memory models semantics isn't relevant, since the map is effectively read-only. Only when you would write some concurrent HashMap, then you need to worry about the memory ordering effects of the items in the array.

Comment: Exactly answer the question and detailed explaination. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is concept here? You returning new hasmaps to various threads? If only one thread will write and read from single hashmap then it's ok. But if you have multiple threads which read/writes on single hashmap then you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, `volatile` isn't enough here to ensure a "happens-before" ordering in this case.

But in this situation, I'm unsure if it's that important.
Consider one thread A:

```
while(true) {
    mapCache.reload();
}
```

And another thread B:

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println(mapCache.get(key));
}
```

Whether `reload()` is synchronized or not, the output you get from Thread B is dependent on when the `get(String)` actually happens. It could really fall on either the old or new map.

**The reason** `volatile` is not enough is because although the updated reference in your `map` field will be immediately visible to all threads, your operation itself to update that field is not synchronized or atomic.

For example, one thread might call `reload()` then another call `get(String)` but before that first thread *actually* changes what Map is referenced by `map` the second thread may have already read from the old `map`. It's for this reason that you would need synchronization to block threads from calling `get` while another thread is in the middle of updating the map with `reload`.

Comment: If `reload` and `get` are called ~simultaneously, then `get` retrieving from the old or new map might both be fine (and safe) results. It depends how this is used I think.

Comment: @MikeFHay Yeah, that was my point in saying it might not matter because what you end up with really depends on *when* you read, so there's more to this concurrency question than just this `MapCache` class.

Comment: ```volatile``` is not a memory barier. It doesn't guarantee any thread synchronization. And usage of volatile is narrowed to very specialized use cases. Usage shown by OP is totally wrong, and never should be proposed in first place.

Comment: @TheTosters Not sure why this comment is attached to my answer, as I think I cover what you're saying: "The reason volatile is not enough is because although the updated reference in your map field will be immediately visible to all threads (due to the field being volatile), your operation itself to update that field is not synchronized (with memory barriers,) or atomic" *parenthesis added for context*.

Comment: I agree with you, although it's unclear about my specific use case.  I think the reader thread will see either the old or the new map instance, which is Ok for me. The reader will see a valid inner map structure every time, because of volatile write has happens-before effect.

Comment: @TheTosters To my knowledge, volatile in Java >=1.5 does create a memory barrier.

Comment: @ChenLi If you're ok with the reader seeing either the old or new map, then there's not much need for volatile or synchronization. I think you misunderstand the volatile "happens-before" effect, it only applies to the actual read/write instructions for that field (not the object), the rest of your code could happen in any order unless you synchronize it.

Comment: @xtratic But there is safe publication issue here. Even after each time writer updating the map reference, the map content is effectively immutable, volatile here is still needed for safe publication. In JCIP, author pointed out that two things can go wrong with improperly published objects. 1) Other threads could see a stale value for the holder field, and thus see a null reference or other older
value even though a value has been placed in holder 2) Other threads could see an up-todate value for the holder reference, but stale values for the state of the
Holder.

Comment: @ChenLi But in this case, for the same reasons stated in my answer, `volatile` alone does not provide you safe publication. To avoid the possibility in #1 of getting a null reference, you could just load the map initially and #2 is not an issue for you since you're always creating a new reference to a new map object when you reload.

Comment: @ChenLi To be extra clear: **You still need synchronization to ensure safe publication in this case**. Actually in many cases you stilll require synchronization to ensure safe publication! But based on you saying `"I think the reader thread will see either the old or the new map instance, which is Ok for me"` it doesn't seem to really matter to you, so just avoid a letting the reference be null and you should be good.

Comment: His example uses safe publication. The newly created hashmap is stored in the MapCache.map field which is volatile. And since the HashMap is effectively immutable (doesn't get updated after it is published) no further synchronization is needed. For more information see my answer which gives a full explanation of the happens-before edge.

Comment: @xtratic I get your point that map may be null since I did not mention initialization. I'll make it clear in the question. It's amazing I can read great books like JCIP and discuss tech details with people like you from all over the world!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ensure that at any time, callers of get will see the content of the same latest map instance.
>
> ...is `volatile HashMap` enough...?

Making the `map` variable `volatile` is *not* sufficient to ensure that one thread calling `map.get("foobar")` will see the latest value that some other thread `put` into the map under that key. In fact, it won't even guarantee that the internal structure of the map will appear to be valid when the first thread calls `get`.

Declaring `volatile Map<...> map` does *not* make the map volatile. There is no such thing as a volatile object in Java. Only variables can be volatile.
The fact that the `map` variable is `volatile` only matters when some thread
assigns the variable (e.g., when some thread calls your `reload()` method.)

Comment: It is not accurate. It claims that volatile is not enough. Since the map is effectively immutable, the array won't get updated after it is published and hence volatile is sufficient for safe publication. See my answer for the exact details.